# Operacion resultante entre 2 columnas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Me ocupa lo siguiente:
Tengo el siguiente codigo SQL

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN monto>0 THEN monto ELSE 0 END) AS 'pos', SUM(CASE WHEN monto<0 THEN monto ELSE 0 END) AS 'neg' FROM billetera WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usua' AND  status = '1'
```

Este codigo me da como resultado 2 columnas una con un resultado positivo y otra con un resultado negativo, quisiera obtener el dato directamente desde la consulta mysql para no hacer la operacion desde PHP, por ello me interesa obtener el calculo resultante entre esos 2 numeros es decir al numero positivo restarle el numero negativo y obtener ese resultado, intente haciendo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN monto>0 THEN monto ELSE 0 END) AS 'pos', 
SUM(CASE WHEN monto<0 THEN monto ELSE 0 END) AS 'neg', 
SUM ('pos')+ SUM ('neg') AS 'res'
FROM billetera 
WHERE id_usuario = '2' 
AND  status = '1'
```

y logicamente no procesa el resultado que deseo.

Comment: Basta con que uses `SUM(Monto)`

Comment: Caramba me dio risa la cosa, ciertamente es lo que requiero, muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer mi consulta.